# How to paginate in a subset of MongoDB result

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query

I've got 1 million entries in a collection. After my query I receive 500 entries for user_id = X. I am looking now for one entry of this subset and 5 before and 5 after this item. What would be best strategy?

For the beginning I just select the 500 items:
`db.items.find({"user_id": 1}).limit(500);`

I could now loop through 500 items to find my current item but it seems to me very inconvenient. Is there maybe a better way?

Comment: I think you may want to look at this for inspiration:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703319/mongodb-ranged-pagination

Comment: what determines your "current" or single entry of this subset?