# Node.js mongodb native driver has a "Skip" limit of 23121

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using version 1.3.23 of the native mongodb native node driver:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb

I have to query around 180k of records so I wrote a script that throttles multiple paginated requests.  The problem is, once skip hits anything over 23121 the response no longer returns results.

If I hit my db directly I can return results with any valid skip value so this issue seems to be at the mongo driver level.

Do I just need to upgrade to v1.4.22 (I'm holding this off unless I absolutely need to)?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing any bugs in the JIRA for this issue. If you're sure you can reproduce it, you probably should report it. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-94?jql=project%20%3D%20NODE%20AND%20text%20~%20skip

Comment: Do not paginate with skip and limit. It performs terribly. Paginate using a sort (on `_id` if no need for sort except for paginate). This [old SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960815/range-query-for-mongodb-pagination) has some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the CursorStream for large queries and I would also suggest upgrading to at least 1.4.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/cursorstream.html

Comment: CursorStream solved my problem.  I will still be creating a ticket for the "skip" bug, it did not work in v1.4.x either.