# find() operation taking longer time when MongoDB collection contains docs around 200K

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My MongoDB database contains a collection with 200 k documents. I'm trying to fetch all documents in NodeJS as follows

```
var cursor = collection.find({}, {
 "_id" : false,
}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    callback(null, docs);
});
```

The above operation is taking longer time and I could not able to get results. Is there any way to optimize find operation to get the result ?

NodeJS driver version :2.0
MongoDB version       :3.2.2

**I can easily load data from json raw file but I could not able to do it from MongoDB**

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you really need all the documents? Do you have to load them all to memory?
If you don't need all of them - query only the relevant documents. If you don't have to load all of them to memory - iterate over them.

Comment: Yes, I need all document to show in UI filter by some criteria.

Comment: Do you show all 200k documents in the UI? If not, can the UI send you the filter criteria and you'd build a query based on it?

Comment: Is there any problem if I load all document to UI ?

Comment: I want to show the results some think like google search

Comment: People can't do a lot with 200k items in the UI. Google shows only 10 results per page, for good reason. Sounds like pagination can help you. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960815/range-query-for-mongodb-pagination

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! Thank a lot. One doubt I have in my mind is why the query is very slow at least in NodeJS code. Can't we fetch all documents at least to NodeJs level

Answer (score 1):

People can't do a lot with 200k items in the UI. Google shows only 10 results per page, for good reason. Sounds like pagination can help you. Here's an example: [Range query for MongoDB pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960815/range-query-for-mongodb-pagination)