# How to get the total number of documents with minimongo from a RemoteDb collection without downloading all documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minimongo

When using [`minimongo`](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo) with a `RemoteDb` collection, I do not want to fetch thousands of <del>rows</del> documents then paginate them on the client, but I'd rather fetch them partially, as the user needs, and cache them on a local collection (e.g. `MemoryDb`, using an `HybridDb`). However doing so does not provide the total number of <del>rows</del> documents on the remote database, only the partially fetch (and cached) data.

How do people handle collections containing potentially hundreds of thousands of <del>rows</del> documents with Minimongo? Is that paradigm ignoring the number of document and just provides to the user a way to paginate "next" without knowing how many pages there are?

In other words, if the user searches items, and the app creates a selector for that search, how can the user know how many results there are without downloading potentially hundreds of thousands of <del>rows</del> documents through the `RemoteDb` collection?

Comment: MongoDB, and thus minimongo, is a NoSQL, document based database - it has no concept of 'rows'.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960815/range-query-for-mongodb-pagination#21040304) is a good demo of how to handle pagination using MongoDB queries.

Comment: Again with semantics! Seriously StackOverflow has become unpleasant. Row... documents... sorry but your comment doe snot help resolve this question.

Comment: Apologies if you view that as semantics, however, I do not. In the context of databases, "row" contains meaning.. When you are using a term that does not apply to a specific type of database, how am I supposed to know what "row" means in the context you're using it in? For all I know you could have a single document with a field that is an array, and you're referring to that array as a "row"... A row could be anything.. it sounds like you are referring to a [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/)

Comment: If you are looking for a specific answer, for how to resolve a specific issue, specific terminology is required.. With that being said, and as I included in my original comment, [this answer outlines how to query MongoDB for pagination results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960815/range-query-for-mongodb-pagination#21040304). That link shows you how you can use MongoDB queries for pagination, without having to return thousands of "rows".  Perhaps, you should appreciate the quality of Stack Overflow and how people on this site wish to provide the best possible advice as possible.

Comment: I am aware of MongoDB queries, how to paginate, etc. The question is about Minimongo, and how to get a `count` of a given selector without requiring fetching all **documents** from a  `RemoteDb` collection.