# Get certain amount of documents after a particular ObjectId in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection called `Messages` which looks like this

```
{
  _id: "6106b76f07e61c072c3587ad",
  content: "this is an example content",
}
```

Suppose I have around 1000 items in this collection, and I want to query documents in batches of 10, based on the `_id` that I will provide i.e., **10 items after a particular _id**

Consider this collection as shown,

```js
[
  {
    _id: "1",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  {
    _id: "4",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  {
    _id: "5",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  {
    _id: "6",
    content: "this is an example content",
  },
  .
  .
  ... 1000 such items
]
```

What I want is to query these documents based on the last _id that I send.

**Example**

**Initially**, `LastID = null`

For `_id = null`, Send 1st `10` items

Now `LastID` becomes `10` **(or whatever _id the last element has)**

For `_id = 10`, Send 10 documents **after** _id = 10

Comment: do these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703319/mongodb-ranged-pagination https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040304/2282634

Comment: Yeah, this solved my problem. Thanks @Joe