# PHP MongoDB find query

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I try use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703319/mongodb-ranged-pagination/9704204#9704204) for pagination in PHP:

```
public function getRecords($page, $count, $currentId)
{
    $query = ["_id" => ['$gt' => $currentId]]; //what's wrong here?
    $cursor = $this->recordsCollection->find($query)->
    skip(($page-1) * $count)->
    limit($count)->
    sort(["_id" => true]);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        array_push($result, $doc);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

But it returns an empty array `result`. Also I tried this query without `skip` and `limit`, but the result still was an empty array. If `$query` is empty, everything is ok, it returns all records in colection.

What I'm doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**
`$query = ["_id" => ['$gt' => new MongoId($currentId)]];`

Comment: Maybe `$currentId` is of wrong type? Looking at what you're trying to do I think it should be instance of `MongoId`

Comment: You right. `$query = ["_id" => ['$gt' => new MongoId($currentId)]];` works. Please, make an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Glad it works, added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `$currentId` is of wrong type? Looking at what you're trying to do I think it should be instance of `MongoId`