# mongo db skip takes too long time

Tags: mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo)

I created a simple test:

```
> db.t.count()
7852054
> db.t.find().skip( 1500000 ).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fc078aa82618808f416e372"), "value" : 1500000 }
>
```

To do paging using skip and limit takes too long in huge collections.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: I have another application keep on inserting values:
  for i in xrange(0,99999999):
    db.t.insert( {"value":i} )
so that skip 1500000 takes more than 5 seconds. After I stop the inserting application. skip 1500000 response within one second. But skip 12000010 tasks about 5 seconds.

Comment: could you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to do pagination. give a pageno, and show the records from page_size*pageno to page_size*(pageno+1)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D)?

> Unfortunately skip can be (very) costly and requires the server to
>   walk from the beginning of the collection, or index, to get to the
>   offset/skip position before it can start returning the page of data
>   (limit). As the page number increases skip will become slower and more
>   cpu intensive, and possibly IO bound, with larger collections.
>
> Range based paging provides better use of indexes but does not allow
>   you to easily jump to a specific page.