# Alternative to skip and limit for mongoose pagination with arbitrary sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, pagination, mongoose

Let me start by saying that I've read ([MongoDB - paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049992/mongodb-paging)) that using skip and limit for pagination is bad for performance and that its better to sort by something like `dateCreated` and modify the query for each page.

In my case, I'm letting the user specify the parameter to sort by. Some may be alphabetical. Specifying a query for this type of arbitrary sorting seems rather difficult.

**Is there a performance-friendly way to do pagination with arbitrary sorting?**

Example

```
mongoose.model('myModel').find({...})
        .sort(req.sort)
        ...
```

Secondary question: At what scale do I need to worry about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo)

Comment: For cases where this type of flexible sorting is required, you need to use `skip` and `limit` and live with the performance.  Consider adding indexes to the commonly sorted on columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think you can do this.

but in my opinion the best way is to build you query depending on your req.sort var.
for example (it's written in coffescript)

```
userSort = {name:1} if req.sort? and req.sort="name"
userSort = {date:1} if req.sort? and req.sort="date"
userSort = {number:1} if req.sort? and req.sort="number"


find {}, null , {skip : 0 , limit: 0, sort : userSort } , (err,results)->
```