# Paginate auto load MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Ok so I know how to do this in MySQL but I am unsure how about to do it in MongoDB

I need away to only show 20 items but be able to when a user scrolls to the end of the page to load more older items

in MYSQL is

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name,message FROM paginate ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $position, $items_per_group");
```

but in MongoDB to limit somthing is easy `->limit(20)`
but how do I get older `_id` then the last `_id` loaded?

BTW: this is the site code I am testing I am turn using simular coding to this step by step

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll

But instead of Mysql I will be using MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can query for documents with an older `_id` with the [`$lt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operator. This will return documents that were inserted before `last_id`.

```
db.collection.find( { _id: { $lt: last_id } } ).limit(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort your results and then skip the first `n * 20` results, where n is the  number of times the user reaches the bottom of the page, and then limit the results to 20. So you would keep a counter for `n` and perform a query such as the following:

```
var n = 0;
db.paginate.find({}, { "name" : 1, "message" : 1 }).sort({ "_id" : -1).skip(n).limit(20);
n++;
...
```

However, if I may suggest, it might be expensive to run this query as often as every 20 items. You might want to fetch a larger batch of items, say 200, store them in an array of documents on the client and then draw them as needed. Also, there are libraries such as Airbnb's [Infinity.js](http://airbnb.github.io/infinity/) that are really good at drawing these infinite scrolls. You might want to check them out.

Comment: Just note that `skip()` can be pretty expensive with a lot of pages. See [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo)

Comment: Can I ask Should I limit the max results like twitter only allows 100 results when you do a search or a hash tag

Comment: @RussellHarrower, that is probably a good idea. Again, this depends on your design, but I would definitely suggest you don't query MongoDB every 20 records. Fetch more and then draw them incrementally.

Comment: @JustinCase, noted. Thanks for the link!