# how to handle a huge amount of data in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, minimongo

I have a pagination bar that controls what data I display in a table (I re-subscribe every time I move to a new page). the collection that I'm working with has 25,000 documents and it may get up tp 100,000 documents. Everything seems to be working as expected for the first couples of pages but after the 8th page things start getting slower and slower, and if I jump from 1 to 10 at once data doesn't load (same if I jump from 1 to the last one 2546th). I have been checking the values for skip and limit in both when I subscribe and publish and they are ALWAYS correct, so the question is, is there any better way to handle a lot of data in subscribe and publish???? this is part of my code

```
// both
c_frameworks = new Mongo.Collection("framework");

//client
var skip = this.data.limit * obj.page // page number 0 ... 2546
Meteor.subscribe("framework", skip, this.data.limit);
Template.myT.helper({
    return c_frameworks.find({}, {
                                  sort: ["_id", "asc"],
                                  skip: this.skip, 
                                  limit: this.limit
                                  });
});

// server
Meteor.publish("framework", function (mySkip, myLimit) {
    check(mySkip, Number);
    check(myLimit, Number);
    return c_frameworks.find({}, {sort: ["_id", "asc"], skip: mySkip, limit: myLimit});
});
```

UPDATE:

I just found this info, that it says why this approach is very slow but the solution is not the desired one

[Slow pagination over tons of records in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo)

Comment: juanp do me a favor put a `console.log` inside the helper and tell me how many times you see the `console.log `

Comment: done! 20 times, the same amount of this.limit, I'll update my question with some information that I just found

Comment: well if you get the console.log 20 times, just think the helper its running 20times, so thats means you are runing 20 times the query.

Comment: good call! :-) I fixed that bug, the first couples of pages load faster but the problem remains after the 10th page

Comment: Did you destroy the page every team you leave the page? Template.example.destroy something like that, so each page will be fresh

Comment: nop, Meteor takes care of that, since this template is reactive, when the content of the collection (in the client) change, the content of my table change as well giving the illusion that you are moving forward or backward