# exposing database read operations as webservice

Tags: mongodb, web-services, rest

I'm writing an REST API to database service(mongodb, django). My question is how to handle read operations through API? one simple sol'n is to query the database with skip and limit params on every api call, so i can query database and return the results. But wont it be inefficient to make a query on every api call(pagination)? Or should I query once and store cursor_id on first call in backend and use is to fetch data for subsequent api calls?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go with your simple solution: just query to the db the appropriate page number. Use provided `skip()` and `limit()` methods, or if you care a lot about efficiency, in [this thread there is a work around avoiding `skip()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo)

In general terms, I would not recommend to load in memory a whole db collection/table (nor mongo but any db).
That could work with a tiny dataset, but, what if your collection holds around 200k documents? are you going to keep them in a variable? you'll waste the CPU memory **duplicating** your db.
Apart, you'll find **inconsistency** data between what is loaded in the db and what do you have in memory.
Finally, how many times will your API search for page number 2000? Usually you'll look for the first results page.