# How can I query a mongo database to start at a certain index to another certain index without skip?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

For example: If I have a collection of 25 records. I want to use something like `db.collection.find(indexOf[14]).limit(4)` I do not think this is possible, but basically I want to say start at this point in the mongo query and find me the next `n` records.

`indexOf` may not be the best example, but basically I want to start the search a certain index and find the next `n` records and return those.

I know you can use the `.skip()` method, but as they said in the documentation it is bad on the CPU to use that. So I do not want to use that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/

You would use something similar to your example:

```
users = db.users.find({'_id'> last_id}).limit(10);
```

Is this what you've tried?

Comment: The problem here is that my id's are completely randomized. And very long strings.

Comment: I understand.  When you say you don't want to use `.skip()` because it's bad on CPU, how large is the data you're trying to page over?  Is it a huge result set?  Usually you're not going to return  a list of more than a few thousand results to a user anyway?  The warning about .skip() being CPU intensive might not be an issue .

Comment: This is a project for a large company so many many thousands and even hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you change your mind and consider using `$skip`. Unless your pagination feature is so core to your system that users will be using it all the time and unless you are dealing with a massive number of clients or documents it is unlikely that `$skip` will cause you serious trouble.

If you are really worried about that topic then run a benchmark and have a look at what your CPU/response time does.

Also check the responses here: [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongodb)