# .count aggregate significantly slows execution time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, geonear

I am refactoring some old code to hope to speed up and make information more secure.  In order to do so I am trying to use the MongoDB aggregation framework to get all users near a specific location.  Originally this was being solved by handling some spherical calculations on the front end but to do so it was sending `lat, lng` coordinates of each user back to the front end which is insecure and exposes location data of users un-necessarily.

My solution is use the aggregation framework and `$geoNear` to get the list of nearby users and then also populate a field with the distance in miles called `distanceAway`.  Everything is working well until I try to set up pagination.  The `$count` stage slows the execution of the route dramatically.

Below is my code:

```
module.exports = async function findUsersNearLocationAggregate(baseLocation, page = 1, limit = 20) {
    // quick validation on location object passed
    if(!lodash.get(baseLocation, 'geometry.location', undefined)) 
        throw new Error('NO_LOCATION_SPECIFIED')

    //  Grab user location to use as location origin
    const { lat, lng } = baseLocation.geometry.location

    let query = {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat] },
            distanceField: "distanceAway",
            spherical: true,
            distanceMultiplier: CONVERT_METERS_TO_MILES
        }
    }

    const users = await User.aggregate([
        query,
        { $skip: ((page - 1) * limit) },
        { $limit: limit }
    ])

    // const [{ count }] = await User.aggregate([
        // query,
        // { $count: 'count' }
    // ])

    return {
        user: users,                    
        // totalPages: Math.ceil(count / limit)
        // currentPage: page
    }
}
```

This function was meant to return the list of users (`limit` of 20 at a time) and show other data such as `totalPages` and `currentPage` to track the pagination on the front-end and make subsequent requests.

When I comment out the following line:

```
    const [{ count }] = await User.aggregate([
        query,
        { $count: 'count' }
    ])
```

the execution of the route that uses the call is max 100ms.
When I comment it in the call jumps to approx 1100ms.

Is there someway to get the pagination data I am looking for without a significant increase in request time?  10X seems quite large.

Comment: your issue seems partially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongodb

Comment: also check your indexes for $geoNear stage

Comment: thanks @kiko075 .  It is definitely using IXSCAN and my field for $geoNear is indexed properly via `.explain("executionStats")`.  I'll check out the above link