# How to fetch limit data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database which store historical data of sensors. Each time I could type a command 'get 1' to get 1,000 data from server. If user type a command 'get 2', he can retrieve another 1,000 data and the whole database is sorted by time. How to retrieve data with query? Also, I concern the performance of database.

This is one of the record format. I have more than 1 billions data in server.

[image]

Comment: use cursor https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by using `$skip` and `$limit`.

But a better solution is you get the first 1k documents and then you request another 1k documents with date. Such as below example.

First: 1k docs, date between them are 20210805 ~ 20211016.
Second: `$sort`, `{ $match: {date: {$lt: 20210805}}}`, $limit:1000

Comment: Thank for you answer. My sampling time doesn't have fixed sampling time interval. I can't use match to do it. $skip may be a good solution in this database