# MongoDB Aggregation : - how to make a fast mongodb aggregation query

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have 2 collections of users and attendances.
I am trying to get user's attendance data from attendance collection and merge them
with lookup and set the condition I want to execute to get attendance data
and then again I set the whole attendance data by using reduce to get less data

and this query takes 1 minute to execute locally with 150mbps internet speed
which is a very very slow execution and guess what i have 1000 user but i am only trying to get 10 users and it taking so long time

I want this to be executed within 300ms

```js
const attendanceData = await User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        lastLocationId: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(typeId),
        isActive: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        workerId: 1,
        workerFirstName: 1,
        workerSurname: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "attendances",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "employeeId",
        as: "attendances",
      },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        attendances: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$attendances",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: ["$$this.Date", new Date(fromDate)],
                },
                {
                  $lte: ["$$this.Date", new Date(toDate)],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.createdAs", dataType],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.status", true],
                },
                {
                  $eq: ["$$this.workerType", workerType],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        attendances: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$attendances",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                [
                  {
                    _id: "$$this._id",
                    createdAs: "$$this.createdAs",
                    Date: "$$this.Date",
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { $skip: 0 },
    { $limit: 10 },
  ]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongodb)