# Mongo Sort Error on _id field - Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my MEAN stack project, I get this mongo sort error **for _id field** for a collection.
"_id" field is indexed by default. Then why would this error appear for sorting on _id field?

```
"Server Error in fetching Reports: 
MongoError: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: 
errmsg: "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.""
```

Node Method Code:

```
  // docQuery is defined earlier in the code depending on filter conditions
  docQuery = PCheckNew.find(pClientIdFilterObj).collation({ locale: 'en'});

  const selectStr = 'ourSrNo batchId fy month investorId platform portfolioShName broker fName mName lName pan dob mobile clientId clientName pCheckedOn pCheckSummary'

  ///// this is to find out the correct count of documents matching the search/filter criteria
  fetchedDocs = await docQuery.select(selectStr).lean().exec();
  if(!fetchedDocs) fetchedDocs = [];
  totalCount = fetchedDocs.length;
  if(!totalCount) totalCount = 0;

  // apply pagination and sort
  // although the below code allows to sort on any field, In angular mat table the sort is disabled. Therefore sortKey is null always.

  if(totalCount > 0) {
    if(pageSize && pageIndex >= 0) {
      if(!sortKey) {
        sortKey = '_id'
      }
      if(!sortOrder) {
        sortOption = '-' + sortKey
      } else {
        if(sortOrder === 'desc') {
          sortOption = '-' + sortKey
        } else {
          sortOption = sortKey
        }
      }
      console.log('sortOption', sortOption);  // output '-_id'

      ////// ERROR ON BELOW LINE
      docQuery.select(selectStr).sort(sortOption).skip(pageSize * pageIndex).limit(pageSize);
    }
    fetchedDocs = await docQuery.lean().exec();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow pagination over tons of records in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongodb)